# Codeigniter - SQL query from view

Tags: codeigniter

I know its not meant to be done, but could someone show me how to run an SQL query from a view.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean you want access to your models? You can get the main CodeIgniter object/controller with `get_instance()`, and then access the model through that:

```
$ci =& get_instance();

$ci->Model_name->find(...);
```

Comment: Thanks for that .... Im fairly new to CI ... So i enter that into my view? ... and then replace the 'find' with 'query' ?? could you give me an example of using that to write a query

Comment: You replace find with whatever method you've written to perform the query.